# Getting a android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException on a fallback resource

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I'm seeing in my crash reporting tool a android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException for a resource that I have in drawable-nodpi which, as far as I can tell, acts as fallback. This works fine in my phone and most other devices, but from time to time a device pops with this.
I'm having a feeling that this may have to do with some bug in the tooling, specifically in app bundles, which is what I'm using for deployment.
Here's an example stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException · Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pkg/Activity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable myDrawable with resource ID its id
ActivityThread.java:2951android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity    
ActivityThread.java:3086android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity 
LaunchActivityItem.java:78android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute  
TransactionExecutor.java:108android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks  
TransactionExecutor.java:68android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute    
ActivityThread.java:1816android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage  
Handler.java:106android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage  
Looper.java:193android.os.Looper.loop   
ActivityThread.java:6718android.app.ActivityThread.main 
Method.java:-2java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke   
RuntimeInit.java:493com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
ZygoteInit.java:858com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
```

I have absolutely no clue how to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known effect of incorrectly sideloading the app. Most users have been used to sideloading a single APK, but with the App Bundle, multiple APKs have to be sideloaded at the same time (the base APK + the config split APKs) to work properly. Some other app stores copying apps from the Play Store see the same issue, and users may end up with an incomplete copy of your app.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!